# pgBouncer exceeds connection limit even with idle connections

Tags: postgresql-9.5, pgbouncer

I'm using pgBouncer to balance connections in PostgreSQL.

Sets a limit of 2048 connections in the PostgreSQL main configuration and also in pgBouncer.

It happens that there are several connections in idle and pgBouncer does not use them, trying to create new ones and triggering the error:

```
Pooler Error: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)
```

This is my postgresql.config setting:

```
# DB Version: 9.5
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: oltp
# Total Memory (RAM): 28 GB
# CPUs num: 8
# Connections num: 2048
# Data Storage: ssd

max_connections = 2048
shared_buffers = 7GB
effective_cache_size = 21GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1792MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 3584kB
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 8
```

This is my pgBouncer setting:

```
pool_mode = session

server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL

max_client_conn = 2048

default_pool_size = 2048

min_pool_size = 32
```

I only have one database and one user that connects using pgBouncer.

I sure did something wrong, but I can't identify what it is.
What can it be?

This is the situation of my server.
[image]

[image: Multiple idle connections.]

This is the error message that is displayed even with multiple idle connections.

```
2019-09-02 16:35:33.423 1652 WARNING C-********: (nodb)/(nouser)@***.***.***.***:43682 Pooler Error: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)
2019-09-02 16:35:35.048 1652 WARNING C-********: (nodb)/(nouser)@***.***.***.***:44360 Pooler Error: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)
```

Comment: how about `reserve_pool_size` ? - You can check it by using `show config` in `pgbouncer` database;

Comment: @SahapAsci the reserve_pool_size is commented, and all timeout settings are commented.

Comment: It seems that you are getting more connection than max_client_conn. You can increase the value of max_client_conn  (but not default_pool_size ). The thing is that your max_connection is somehow too high.

Comment: @SahapAsci What value would you recommend for max_client_conn and default_pool_size?

Comment: It's not right to recommend a value (for 3 parameters - [max_connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) , max_client_conn  or default_pool_size ) without understanding the whole environment (web servers, databases, load etc).

Comment: @SahapAsci A server (Apache) that handles about 1500 requests simultaneously makes connections to the database (which is different).
The postgreSQL server is dedicated to database and pgBouncer only (It has 8 vCPUs and 32 GB of RAM.)
When the server starts to slow down, the average load is around 100.
Now with 155 active connections, the average load is at 28.

Comment: IMHO you have more than one issue related performance. I suggest you to get a consultancy which includes both infrastructure (postgres, pgbouncer, apache etc) and the code you have developed.